# Javadoc stopped updating after massive changes

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

For some reason, my Javadoc has stopped detecting changes to class descriptions. For example, I have a class that has the description `A sample of Swing and reference types.` which I changed to `A sample of Swing and reference types. (Page 78)`, but even when I delete all the Javadoc folders and regenerate it, it still says `A sample of Swing and reference types.`. I'm using Javadoc within Eclipse, and I do have the correct Javadoc program selected. Here's another program which won't generate the javadoc description at all:

```
package com.nathan2055.booksamples;

/**
 * This program calculates 228 cents of change out.
 * @author Nathan2055
 */

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class CalculatingChange {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 248 cents...
        int total = 248;

        // How many quarters?
        int quarters = total / 25;
        int whatsLeft = total % 25;

        // How many dimes?
        int dimes = whatsLeft / 10;
        whatsLeft = whatsLeft % 10;

        // How many nickels?
        int nickels = whatsLeft / 5;
        whatsLeft = whatsLeft % 5;

        // How many are left?
        int cents = whatsLeft;

        // And then tell me.
        out.println("From " + total + " cents you get:");
        out.println(quarters + " quarters");
        out.println(dimes + " dimes");
        out.println(nickels + " nickels");
        out.println(cents + " cents");


    }

}
```

Comment: I think this is going to prove too localized to help you. My guess is that you're building Javadoc against an old copy somewhere. I suggest you change it to something *completely* different, blow away the Javadoc output folders, and then search your drive for the text "sample of Swing and reference types".

Comment: @JonSkeet - I nuked the doc folder on my drive and then changed the text. It got the changed text, but still refuses to give the `(Page 78)` text at the end of it. There is also another class which it completely refuses to give the docs for, yet it lists it. Weird.

Comment: We'd just be guessing at this point, I'm afraid. Unless you can reproduce this in a short but complete program, I don't think anyone's going to be able to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm adding the code that refuses to generate javadocs now, as my repeated tests still won't get it to work.

Comment: Thanks - I've worked out what's wrong now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
/**
 * This program calculates 228 cents of change out.
 * @author Nathan2055
 */

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class CalculatingChange {
```

The javadoc has to be *directly* before the class declaration. You've got it before the import statement. So while the above doesn't work, this does:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

/**
 * This program calculates 228 cents of change out.
 * @author Nathan2055
 */    
public class CalculatingChange {
```